No Module Found:"Requests" In azure function app
I have deployed the python code to azure function app. Locally there is no issue the program is working fine but when deployed to , it is showing "request module not found" issue. I have included request module in requirements.txt and also the module installed in the function app.


can you please share the function code and requirements.txt file in text format

The error could be due to the incompatibility of module versions.

Add the packages without including the versions in requirements.txt.


I have created a python Azure function and used the below packages in requirements.txt:
azure-functions
requests
mpmath
networkx
numpy
openai
openpyxl
packaging
pdfkit
pillow
pycparser
pydantic
pydantic-core
pymongo
pyYaml
regex
requests
safetensors
scikit-learn

init.py:
import logging
import requests
from azure.functions import HttpRequest, HttpResponse

def main(req: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    url = "https://www.example.com"
    response = requests.get(url)
    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.{response}")
    else:
        return HttpResponse(
            "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
            status_code=200
        )


Deploy the function using func tools :

func azure functionapp publish <functionapp_name> --build remote



Portal:


